# Why can't I call goog.require() in the same code block in which I call a function from the loaded library?

Tags: google-closure-library

Here is my html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="sayHi()">
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my hello.js file.

```
var options = {
    "style" : "background:#EEE;"
}

function sayHi() {
  goog.require("goog.dom");
  var header = goog.dom.createDom("h1", options, "hello world");
  goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, header);
}
```

Why does Chrome Console issue this error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDom' of undefined
```

In general, I don't think I can require a library in the same code block in which I call a function from the library. I just saw this in the documentation, but I was wondering why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In uncompiled Closure code, each `goog.require(NAMESPACE)` results in a call to:

```
document.write('<script src="SCRIPT_PROVIDING_NAMESPACE"></script>');
```

The dependencies are defined with calls to `goog.addDependency(relativePath, provides, requires)` in deps files generated with [depswriter.py](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/depswriter). Using the Chrome Developer Tools, the Elements tab shows all of the `<script>` elements dynamically inserted based on the Closure Library dependencies defined in [deps.js](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/deps.js).

In your example, when `sayHi()` is triggered by the body `onload` event, a new `<script>` element is inserted in the header. However, this new `<script>` element has not yet loaded `goog.dom`. Therefore, `goog.dom` is undefined.

If you change **hello.js** as follows:

```
goog.require("goog.dom");

var options = {
    "style" : "background:#EEE;"
}

function sayHi() {
  var header = goog.dom.createDom("h1", options, "hello world");
  goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, header);
}
```

Then `goog.require("goog.dom")` gets executed prior to the `onload` event and the inserted `<script>` element has a chance to load `dom.js` prior to the call to `sayHi()`.